# How to fix first page with Rails' Turbolinks and Wistia's Fresh Url

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, history, turbolinks, wistia

When using Wistia's [Fresh Url plugin](https://github.com/wistia/fresh-url), Turbolinks doesn't work on the first page.  For example, if you navigate one page away and click the back button in the browser, the url with change but the page won't actually change at all.  Once you navigate two pages away, though, Turbolinks starts working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh Url uses `window.history.replaceState()` to update the url once it's finished, and `turbolinks: true` needs to be set.

So, you have to add it to Fresh Url's `FreshUrl.prototype.allReadyCallback()` to be something like...

```
FreshUrl.prototype.allReadyCallback = function() {
    return window.history.replaceState({ turbolinks: true }, "", FreshUrl.cleanUrl());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks doesn't play well with Jquery and asyncronous javascript at the moment, but the changes to it for Rails 5 looks promising.

At the moment I would just advise to disable turbolinks when clicking on the link which leads to the page which uses that plugin. You can do so by adding a `data-no-turbolink` property to the `link_to` helper method like so:

```
<%= link_to some_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => false do %>
  click_me_to_go_to_some_path
<% end %>
```